# Is there a way to know when the PHP -sever has is ready to serve requests?

Tags: php, testing, server

One may start a local PHP server, e.g for testing:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

One can also execute a PHP statement, e.g.

```
php -r "echo 'Hello';"
```

We initially hoped we could use this to tell when the server was started, i.e. using `systemd-notify` or some other process readiness protocol. However, using `-r` and `-S` together seems to ignore `-r`.

My question is thus, when starting a local server using `php -S`, is it possible to execute some code *after* the server is ready to receive incoming connections? This would allow us to execute something like `systemd-notify --ready` and enable the parent process to know when to proceed with testing.